# Merging PDF using PDFBOX give scratch file size of 65536 error on AWS lambda only

Tags: java, aws-lambda, pdfbox

We are using PDFBOX to merge two PDFs

1. File 1 : 35 KB
2. File 2 : 32 KB

While merging, I am getting the error  `Expected scratch file size of 65536 but found 61440`

I am using `MemoryUsuageSetting` using `tempfile` for  the merge, as in

```
pdfMerger.mergeDocuments(MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly());
```

Below is the code in my merge routine

```
List<InputStream> sources (inputsteam of my files to merge)
mergedPDFOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
cosStream = new COSStream();
PDFMergerUtility pdfMerger = new PDFMergerUtility();
pdfMerger.addSources(sources);
pdfMerger.setDestinationStream(mergedPDFOutputStream);
pdfMerger.mergeDocuments(MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly());
```

While calling the above merge routine in AWS lambda, we are getting the same error (`Expected scratch file size of 65536 but found 61440`)

However, if I call our PDF merge routine in a Java main program in my local machine, the files are generated successfully.

Below is the stack trace of the error

```
java.io.IOException: Expected scratch file size of 65536 but found 61440r   at org.apache.pdfbox.io.ScratchFile.enlarge(ScratchFile.java:237)r  at org.apache.pdfbox.io.ScratchFile.getNewPage(ScratchFile.java:167)r   at org.apache.pdfbox.io.ScratchFileBuffer.addPage(ScratchFileBuffer.java:126)r  at org.apache.pdfbox.io.ScratchFileBuffer.<init>(ScratchFileBuffer.java:84)r    at org.apache.pdfbox.io.ScratchFile.createBuffer(ScratchFile.java:403)r at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.createRawOutputStream(COSStream.java:271)r   at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFCloneUtility.cloneForNewDocument(PDFCloneUtility.java:119)r    at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFCloneUtility.cloneForNewDocument(PDFCloneUtility.java:101)r    at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFCloneUtility.cloneForNewDocument(PDFCloneUtility.java:140)r    at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFCloneUtility.cloneForNewDocument(PDFCloneUtility.java:101)r    at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFCloneUtility.cloneForNewDocument(PDFCloneUtility.java:110)r    at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFCloneUtility.cloneForNewDocument(PDFCloneUtility.java:101)r    at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFCloneUtility.cloneMerge(PDFCloneUtility.java:194)r at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFCloneUtility.cloneMerge(PDFCloneUtility.java:225)r at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFCloneUtility.cloneMerge(PDFCloneUtility.java:185)r at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFCloneUtility.cloneMerge(PDFCloneUtility.java:225)r at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFCloneUtility.cloneMerge(PDFCloneUtility.java:174)r at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility.appendDocument(PDFMergerUtility.java:558)r   at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility.legacyMergeDocuments(PDFMergerUtility.java:391)r at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility.mergeDocuments(PDFMergerUtility.java:277)r
```

We are using `PDFBox` version `2.0.12`

Can someone please guide on resolving this issue?

Thanks,
Anjana

Comment: Please add the stack trace of the exception in question.

Comment: Thanks  I have updated stack trace of error along with PDFBox version used.

Comment: We upgraded the PDFBox version to 2.0.16 however still merge fails when routine is called from AWS lambda it still fails with scratch file size. However we changed our routine to use in memory instead of file that works in AWS lambda. We want to understand why temp file is an issue are we missing configuration . Please suggest this is very critical bug for our production.

Comment: I don't have a solution; I suspect a bug in AWS Lambda, there is a java.io.RandomAccessFile.setLength(65536) call in PDFBox, with the file being created with File.createTempFile() but the file size is apparently 61440. Can you try to create such a file and call setLength() ? Are you using the latest jdk?

Comment: If this sounds too complex, I could create a PDFBox version that does more logging. However this is only possible if you 1) create an issue in PDFBox JIRA bug tracker, 2) are able to use jar files directly.

Comment: Hi Tilman, Sure we will create Jira ticket and we can use jar file. we are also investigating on aws lambda side. However can you pls clarify what is the file name pattern used for tmp file pdfbox.  Thanks

Comment: `File.createTempFile("PDFBox", ".tmp", scratchFileDirectory);` scratchFileDirectory is usually null unless you set it yourself. In that case it will use the default temporary-file directory.

Comment: Further discussion is here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4601

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in AWS, just changed the memory usage for the merge from

```
pdfMerger.mergeDocuments(MemoryUsageSetting.setupMixed(MEMORY_USE));
```

to

```
pdfMerger.mergeDocuments(MemoryUsageSetting.setupMainMemoryOnly());
```

And it worked for AWS Lambda,

Hope this helps someone else.

Regards